# for loop over Model List in MVC script and access Jquery inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, populate, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to access jquery inside forloop in MVC script. Here is the scenario:-

I have Model Property of type list. and want to iterate over the loop and add the contents to Dropdown in same view.

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.worklist)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "contactPhone" })

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

@for(var i=0; i < Model.worklist.Count(); i++)
{
   if(Model.worklist[i].PhoneID == 1)
   {
     @:$('<option />').val(Model.worklist[i].PhoneNumber).text(Model.worklist[i].PhoneNumber).appendTo('#contactPhone select');
   }
}

  });
</script>
```

its not working. is there any way I can fill dropdown dynamically like this using other Model property in mvc script  ?

Comment: Why do this in jQuery? Why not in your `DropDownListFor`?

Comment: @JasonP, Actually on screen I have list of phones for the worker and they have can add multiple Cell phone numbers. I have to populate the dropdown with a phonenumbers of type Cell. So in that case I would need jquery function I guess so that I can capture the on change event for the PhoneType dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your selector `#contactPhone select` don't works cause `select` control also has `contactPhone` id. Check with `.appendTo('#contactPhone')`.

BTW, you can use helper to populate dropdown list with your model:

```
@{
    new list = Model.worklist.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
       Text = x.PhoneNumber.ToString(), 
       Value = x.PhoneNumber.ToString()
    }).ToList();
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, list, new { id = "contactPhone" })
```